# How to delete millions of record from mysql table

Tags: mysql, database

In my MySQL table contain more than 20 millions of records . I want to delete it from lower index by running

```
delete FROM mydb.dailyreportdetails where idDailyReportDetails>0 order by idDailyReportDetails asc limit 1000 ;
```

While running the above query i got the error as mention below

```
Operation failed: There was an error while applying the SQL script to the database.
ERROR 1205: 1205: Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction
SQL Statement:
```

**Is there have any way to run query in mysql background or any faster steps to delete those record ?**

Comment: You can better run cron job in your project for certain time interval for removing your unwanted records regularly

Comment: is idDailyReportDetails column auto increment key in dailyreportdetails table ? can you please share the schema.

Comment: That statement deletes a maximum of 1000 records, not millions. Clearly it is the query part that is taking the time, not the deletion. Is `idDailyReportDetails` indexed?

Comment: You can increase the innodb_lock_wait_timeout. It would be better if you delete unrequired records periodically to avoid this issue. You can use cron jobs for this like [SQLyog](https://www.webyog.com/product/sqlyog).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could first find the actual id to delete...

```
SELECT idDailyReportDetails 
    FROM mydb.dailyreportdetails 
    where idDailyReportDetails>0 
    order by idDailyReportDetails asc limit 1000,1 ;
```

Then a straight forward delete, using the value from the select...

```
DELETE FROM mydb.dailyreportdetails 
        where idDailyReportDetails < ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can check the InnoDB locks by

```
SHOW ENGINE InnoDB STATUS;
```

Then you will get the status or error..

If you want to increase the time in your case use

```
set innodb_lock_wait_timeout=3000;
```

After that run your delete query.

Answer (score -1):

The quickest way to delete rows from a table is to reference them by id. This as well is preferable for the binary log. Hence the best way is to use some programming language and in a loop fetch a new group of row ids and then delete the rows by explicitly stating them in the `WHERE idDailyReportDetails IN ()` clause.

Range queries (WHERE id < something) might constantly fail because of locks if the database is used by other processes.

Comment: But it is not necessarily quicker to run a separate query and then a delete statement.